# Getting an assembly's Product property only having an AssemblyName

Tags: .net, reflection, assemblies

I'm getting the [`Product`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyproductattribute.aspx) attribute from all the loaded assemblies in my application using:

```
AssemblyProductAttribute product
    = (AssemblyProductAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(
        assembly, typeof(AssemblyProductAttribute));
```

I would like to get this attribute for all the assemblies that the currently loaded assemblies reference. However [GetReferencedAssemblies()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getreferencedassemblies.aspx) returns an array of `AssemblyName`s, so I can't use the above code to get the `Product` attribute.

Is there a way to get an `Assembly` object from an `AssemblyName` object, or a way to get the `Product` attribute from an `AssemblyName`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can use [`Assembly.Load(AssemblyName)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4cw969y.aspx) to load the assembly - is that good enough for you? Note that once you've loaded the assembly, you won't be able to *unload* it other than by unloading the `AppDomain`. Of course, if those assemblies were going to be loaded anyway, there's no harm done. (Once you've loaded the assembly once into an `AppDomain`, using the same `AssemblyName` again will just return the already-loaded assembly.)

Comment: I believe this should work--I was not sure what the effects of loading an already-loaded assembly would be.

Comment: There shouldn't be an problems, as far as I'm aware - it should return the already-loaded assembly. Will check when I get the chance.

Comment: This solution is not perfect because it turns out that some of my assemblies are referencing other assemblies that are not being included with my software, triggering a FileNotFoundException.

Comment: Surely that's just showing that you have a problem with your assemblies: either you should ship those assemblies, or not depend on them. If you absolutely *have* to have them, I would suggest having a hard-coded list of "ignored assemblies".